# How to select every letter from every word?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, arabic

I'm trying to make my own OCR for Egyptian.

This is my code:

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
import seaborn as sn
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import cv2

image = cv2.imread(
    r"C:\Users\emady\Desktop\VS Code\HandWriten_Arabic\test_select.png")
base_image = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(
    gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 13))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernal, iterations=1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cents[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

chars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
         'ا', 'ب', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'س', 'ش', 'ص',
         'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'ه', 'و', 'ي']

IMAGE_SIZE = (48, 48)


text = ""
TARGET_WIDTH = 48
TARGET_HEIGHT = 48

for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if h > 16 and w > 1:
        roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        cv2.imwrite("temp/index_roi.png", roi)

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (36, 255, 12), 2)
cv2.imwrite("temp/index_bbox_new.png", image)
```

My issue is I detected the boundingRect good and I don't know how to get each word and get the word letters as shown in the image below:[image: Countor Letters]

Comment: Did you try with  `pyteseract` ? Build your own ocr is a big project.

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard yeah it's very hard to build OCR, I tried pyteseract but how to build a custom dataset not clear to me all I got is to insert an image into Jboxeditor and select the letters and save and train is it all about or I'm missing something?

Comment: I know nothing about egiptian, so excuse me, but could be possible that these are arabic characters? If that is true, you can search information about how to configure pyteseract to recognize them. https://www.google.com/search?q=pyteseract+arabian&oq=pyteseract+arabian

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard yeah I know what you mean, the bad thing is our language is very hard xD xD and another bad thing is tesseract is not bad but for Arabic but it can't read handwritten Arabic characters so I need to make my own dataset

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the answer you want, but I think what you're trying to do here is too difficult — it's not the kind of thing a single person can cobble together.

Here's the big issue: Even vanilla OCR for *print, Standard* Arabic is not a solved problem. I was recently trying out `pdfplumber` on a digital (*not* scanned) Arabic pdf, and it did okay with a lot of it. Except that the text outputted backwards (fixable with `bidi` package) and it added spaces wherever there were diacritics (fixable with some preprocessing). But the font was a little bit fancy (from a novel) and pdfplumber completely choked on letters that were stacked on top of one another, like تج in a nice font. It couldn't make out the borders between letters, and the method you're trying here (if I understand it) would have the same problem.

But print Standard Arabic OCR is easy compared to what you're trying to do. Even if you have newspaper-kind of fonts, where the letters are not stacked, an OCR will not do well with vernacular Arabic. It's too different from what it's been trained on, and you'll end up with word salad.

Handwriting in vernacular Arabic just makes all of these difficulties more difficult. I'm not going to say impossible, but very, very difficult.

I think you should start this process by doing a Google Scholar research on the latest articles about "Arabic OCR". This is a problem for well-funded university teams — see what they're doing about it.

Comment: Yea, you are right my Arabic language is one of the hardest languages in the world.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is based on Tesseract:

https://devtools360.com/en/ocr/ara

It does pretty well with Arabic print, even slightly bad quality print, but I'm not sure about handwriting or colloquial Arabic.